# Composite loop nulhomotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology

The context isn't really relevant but I'll write it here anyways. While calculating the mapping torus $M_f = X\times I /\sim$ where $f: X \to X$ is a basepoint-preserving homeomorphism, and $(x,0)\sim (f(x),1)$, I was trying to show that the kernel of $r_*$ and the image of $i_*$ coincide, where $i: X \to M_f$ is the inclusion, and $r: M_f \to S^1$ is the retraction given by $[(x,t)]\mapsto [(x_0,t)]$. (I am ommitting the obvious quotients, in case you are wondering.)

The inclusion of the image into the kernel was easy to prove. However to show the other direction, namely that if $\alpha$ is a loop in $M_f$ and $r \circ \alpha$ is nulhomotopic in $S^1$, then $\alpha$ is homotopic to a loop in $X$, isn't really working out. Of course, the basepoints are fixed. How do I prove this? Intuitively, it makes perfect sense, and probably would not bother much people, but I really need to understand how to prove this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should make clearer how your induced maps $r_*$ and $i_*$ arise. In your sequence of maps:

$X\xrightarrow{i}M_f\xrightarrow{r}S^1$

is $\alpha$ an arbitrary map from $S^1$ to $M_f$ in the middle? So you are trying to show that if $r \circ \alpha$ is null then you can lift $\alpha$ to $X$?

Comment: @AlgTop1854 $\alpha$ is a loop in $M_f$ based at a fixed basepoint $[(x_0,0)]$. Precisely, I am trying to show that if $ r\circ \alpha$ is nulhomotopic in $S^1$ then $\alpha$ is homotopic to a loop in $r^{-1}([(x_0,0)])$. I think I need something like the homotopy lifting property, but I am not really used to the concept so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction of a Mapping Torus forms a fiber bundle with base $S^1$ and fiber $X$ and fiber bundles (more generally fibrations) have the homotopy lifting property, which you can find in numerous standard references on Homotopy Theory.

Comment: The way you have described it, $ r^{-1}([x_0,0]) $ is a fiber, which is $X$ itself, so really the map $\alpha$ "lifts to the fiber" which is a consequence of the homotopy long exact sequence of a fibration (here using the $\pi_1$ portion of it).  Once you are talking about kernel = image, that is the best interpretation.